# Where clause in pivot table with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.1

I have three database tables.

`fb_pages`, `languages`, `fb_page_likes`.

The table `fb_pages` saves facebook pages and some data to it

```
+----+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | page_categories_id |   facebook_id   | facebook_username | facebook_name | facebook_category | facebook_likes | creator |              permalink              |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |                  2 | 552825254796051 | mesutoezil        | Mesut Özil    | Athlete           |       28540064 |         | https://www.facebook.com/mesutoezil | 2015-07-14 10:09:30 | 2015-08-25 16:43:35 |
+----+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The second table `languages` contains languages that are used to check which `facebook_page` has how many fans in which country

```
+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | language |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | ID       | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 |
|  2 | TR       | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 |
+----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And the third table `fb_page_likes` is just a pivot table to check which fan page has how many likes in which country

```
+----+-------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | language_id | facebook_page_id |  likes  |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+-------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 |                1 | 3271717 | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 |
|  2 |           2 |                1 | 1588001 | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 |
|  3 |           3 |                1 | 1464810 | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 | 2015-08-25 16:38:35 |
+----+-------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

What I want to do now, is to get a FacebookPage and see how many likes it has in a specific country.

For example: I want to check how many likes Mesut Oezil has from users with the language `TR`.

And that's the problem I am currently having, because I don't know how to get that data. I managed to get all languages that are assigned to a page, but I want to get the likes for specific pages.

In my Model `FacebookPage` I created a belongsToMany relationship

```
public function languages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class, 'language_page_likes');
}
```

and in my `Language` model I did it as well

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(FacebookPage::class, 'language_page_likes');
}
```

I learned that this is the way to define a many to many relation ship in laravel. Now, with

`\App\Models\FacebookPage::find(1)->languages;`

I'm getting all languages in which a page has fans, but I want to have the likes for specific countries. Either fro a single country, or a group of countries.

I also tried it like this

```
App\Models\FacebookPage::find(1)->with(['languages' => function($query){
    return $query->where('language_id', 1);
}])->get()
```

but this somehow gives me now all facebook pages instead of the one with id 1.

Also, I would like to get all Likes of Mesut Oezil from Germany, and likes from Mesut Oezil from German, Austria and Switzerland. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I now managed to do it. If someone has a better approach, then please tell me. (Gonna clean up the code up a bit, though)

```
$languages = [1, 2, 3];
$page = \FBFeedParser\Models\FacebookPage::with(['languages' => function($query) use ($languages) {
    $query = $query->select(['language', 'likes']);
    $query = $query->where('language_id', $languages[0]);
    if (sizeof($languages) === 1) {
        return $query;
    }
    unset($languages[0]);
    foreach ($languages as $language) {
        $query = $query->orWhere('language_id', $language);
    }
    return $query;
}])->find(1);
print $page->facebook_name;
print '<hr>';
foreach ($page->languages as $language) {
     print $language->language . ' // ' . $language->likes . '<br>';
}
```